# Use a declared variable in the mailto hyperlink

Tags: asp.net

I have a variable which is passed over from another C# class using the `Request.QueryString[]`, now I want to take the value of that variable and use it in the mailto hyperlink. I don't want to hard code the email address.

The normal mailto link is:

`<a href"mailto:user1234@gmail.com: />`

what I want to do is take the email provided by the user from a previous page...

I have: `Request.QueryString["newEmail"];`

I tried this: `<a href="mailto:Request.QueryString["newEmail"]" />`

but it doesn't work, please help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `asp:HyperLink` which gets rendered as the anchor tag.

'Example:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="EmailLink" runat="server"
        NavigateUrl='<% "mailto:" + Request.QueryString["newEmail"] %>'>
    Send Mail
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have: RequestQueryString["newEmail"];

Should be `Request.QueryString["newEmail"]`.

Your question doesn't show where you're passing this "newEmail" to the query string.

> I tried this: `<a href="mailto:RequestQueryString["newEmail"]" />`

Unless that's a back-end string, you can't combine front-end and back-end code like this. You'd need to wrap it with `<% %>`, and even then you'd not do this because you'd need checks on whether the query string contains a value.

Back-end:

```
protected string email = "";

public string GetEmail() {
    return email;
}

protected virtual void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Request.QueryString["newEmail"] != null)
        email = Request.QueryString["newEmail"];
}
```

Front-end:

```
<a href="mailto:<%# GetEmail() %>"></a>
```

Comment: Typing error, it still doesn't work with Request.QueryString["newEmail"]. Is it possible not to hard code the email address in this hyperlink though <a href"mailto:" /> ??

Comment: I've updated my answer. Do note that I'm not much of an ASP.NET developer, so this may not be a perfect solution.

Comment: It's a front-end string, I have a web form (form1.aspx)that has a textbox where the users enters a new email then there is a send button which redirects to the sendnotification.aspx.cs where there is the mailto link. The 'newEmail' is passed from the form1.aspx to sendnotification.aspx.cs